# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel

Tags: laravel, exception

i'm getting trouble in getting the data from foreign key 
that i wanna get the information from table media
already make relation between 2 tables, but still error give me this `Trying to get property of non-object`in spite of my table have data between those tables

> Modal Dossier

```html
 public function media(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Media');
    }
```

> Modal Media

```html
    public function dossier(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Dossier');
    }
```

> and that my view

i sent the variable $dossier and i did loop 
i trying to get all info

```html
 @if($dossier->media)
                        <?php $ext=substr($dossier->media->url,-3) ;?>
                            <label class="med">
                                @if($ext=='pdf')
                                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
                                @else
                                    <i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></i>
                                @endif
                                    {{$dossier->media->libelle}}
                            </label><a class="btn btn-warning btn-small pull-right" href="documents/{{$dossier->media->url}}"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a>
                                <br><br>
                                <button id="btn-add{{$dossier->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter un Media</button>
                        @else
                            <div class="div1{{$dossier->id}}">
                                <div class="alert alert-warning">Aucune media</div><button id="btn-add{{$dossier->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter un Media</button>
                            </div>

                        @endif
```

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin **$dossier** defined when i did loop

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `$dossier` is null. You should always check if object is `null`, like:

```
@if (is_null($dossier) && $dossier->media)
```

Comment: it show the same result 
the problem is when i write the code like i did nothing show and when i write it whithout @if the message exception display

Comment: Please post result of `dd($dossier);`

Comment: how can i post it

Comment: $dossier not null and table Filled
table **media** have foreing key of table **dossier**

Comment: @QuietMan without seeing data it's impossible to find the error. If you're sure code in your question causes the error, you should post `$dossier` dump somewhere so we'll be able to help you.

Comment: But you said before it's not null. I'm confused. If it's `null`, that's the problem and you should use `is_null($dossier)` check for all similar objects usages.

Answer (score 0):

Check your model `Dossier`, it may be like:

```
public function media(){
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Media', MEDIA_FORIGNKEY);
}
```

Hope this help you!